# How can I point to a name server in a residential network?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting

I am trying to run my own name servers for my domain. Currently the machines on my network are statically set to prioritize my local DNS, which works fine locally.

However, I'm confused about how to make my DNS work outside of my local network. Specifically, I believe that I have tell the domain registrar about my nameservers. And since the nameservers are within the domain, I have to set up glue records for the primary and secondary nameservers. But I'm on a residential network, so I only have one public IP address. How can I direct traffic to those nameservers if I cannot provide public IP addresses unique to them? When I enter my public IP and tell my router to use my local nameservers, it doesn't seem to work.

I'm new to this, so please let me know if I can clarify or am missing anything else. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In small design please dont manage the outside world.

Create your local DNS for your local LAN and leave the public DNS in your registrar nameserver please.

Outside PC will resolve public IP, while in your LAN the PC will resolve local IP, which is perfect.

Comment: You must explain why I shouldn't "manage the outside world" before I will listen to you. As it stands, your response is useless.

Comment: @ate why would you is the question, as I take in consideration its a home network. Your isp allow you to host your NS ? your ISP gave you a static IP to host the NS ? Keep in mind a lot of isp will drop/block inhouse hosting on residential bill.

Comment: The ISP doesn't block port 53, and my IP doesn't change often.